# how to reuse the resultset in mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql, resultset

I have result set like this after executing "select * from temp"

```
id | Month | value1 | value2 |
------------------------------
1  | Apr   | 100    | 150
2  | May   | 50     | 75
3  | Jan   | 50     | 75
5  | Feb   | 50     | 75
6  | mar   | 50     | 75
```

I want to change it to column to rows like pivot table.

i used case when statement to change it.

```
select
    'value1' as Field,

    SUM(CASE 
        WHEN dc.month = 'January' THEN dc.value1 
        ELSE  ''
    END)    AS January,

    SUM(CASE 
        WHEN dc.month = 'February' THEN dc.value1 
        ELSE  ''
    END)    AS February,

    SUM(CASE 
        WHEN dc.month = 'March' THEN dc.value1 
        ELSE  ''
    END)    AS March
      SUM(CASE 
        WHEN dc.month = 'April' THEN dc.value1 
        ELSE  ''
    END)    AS April,

    SUM(CASE 
        WHEN dc.month = 'May' THEN dc.value1 
        ELSE  ''
    END)    AS May
      from
      (select 
         * from 
      temp)dc

Field   | Jan | Feb | Mar | Apr | May
-------------------------------------
Value1  | 50  | 50  | 50  | 100  | 50
```

I want to get same result set for value2 in same query without using UNION. Because temp table has lot of data's.

```
Field   | Jan | Feb | Mar | Apr | May
-------------------------------------
Value1  | 50  | 50  | 50  | 100  | 50
Value1  | 75  | 75  | 75  | 150  | 75
```

Comment: Consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution uses a union, but only to create "fake" rows to represent each value* column, and then joins and groups by those rows:

```
SELECT
    `field`,

    SUM(CASE 
        WHEN dc.month = 'Jan' THEN
            CASE `field`
            WHEN 'value1' THEN dc.value1
            WHEN 'value2' THEN dc.value2
        END
        ELSE  ''
    END)    AS January,

    SUM(CASE 
        WHEN dc.month = 'Feb' THEN
            CASE `field`
            WHEN 'value1' THEN dc.value1
            WHEN 'value2' THEN dc.value2
        END
        ELSE  ''
    END)    AS February,

    SUM(CASE 
        WHEN dc.month = 'Mar' THEN
            CASE `field`
            WHEN 'value1' THEN dc.value1
            WHEN 'value2' THEN dc.value2
        END
        ELSE  ''
    END)    AS March,
      SUM(CASE 
        WHEN dc.month = 'Apr' THEN
            CASE `field`
            WHEN 'value1' THEN dc.value1
            WHEN 'value2' THEN dc.value2
        END
        ELSE  ''
    END)    AS April,

    SUM(CASE 
        WHEN dc.month = 'May' THEN
            CASE `field`
            WHEN 'value1' THEN dc.value1
            WHEN 'value2' THEN dc.value2
        END
        ELSE  ''
    END)    AS May
      FROM
      (SELECT 
         * FROM temp
      )dc
      INNER JOIN (
       SELECT 'value1' AS `field`
            UNION SELECT 'value2'
      ) AS value_columns
    GROUP BY `field`
```

Answer (score 0):

If its just 2 colums i.e. `value1` and `value2` then you can use UNION as **[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/af1d9/9)**

```
select
    'value1' as Field,
    SUM(
        CASE 
        WHEN dc.month = 'Jan' THEN dc.value1 
        ELSE  ''
    END)    AS January,

    SUM(
        CASE 
        WHEN dc.month = 'Feb' THEN dc.value1 
        ELSE  ''
    END)    AS February,

    SUM(
        CASE 
        WHEN dc.month = 'Mar' THEN dc.value1 
        ELSE  ''
    END)    AS March,
      SUM(
        CASE 
        WHEN dc.month = 'Apr' THEN dc.value1 
        ELSE  ''
    END)    AS April,

    SUM(
        CASE 
        WHEN dc.month = 'May' THEN dc.value1 
        ELSE  ''
    END)AS May
from
temp dc

UNION

select
    'value2' as Field,
    SUM(
        CASE 
        WHEN dc.month = 'Jan' THEN dc.value2 
        ELSE  ''
    END)    AS January,

    SUM(
        CASE 
        WHEN dc.month = 'Feb' THEN dc.value2 
        ELSE  ''
    END)    AS February,

    SUM(
        CASE 
        WHEN dc.month = 'Mar' THEN dc.value2 
        ELSE  ''
    END)    AS March,
      SUM(
        CASE 
        WHEN dc.month = 'Apr' THEN dc.value2 
        ELSE  ''
    END)    AS April,

    SUM(
        CASE 
        WHEN dc.month = 'May' THEN dc.value2 
        ELSE  ''
    END)AS May
from temp dc
```

Comment: Its not a just two columns. temp table contains lot of rows. its take more than 15 mins to execute. so i want to use the same result set without using union

Comment: i meant as about the value1 and value2 which are columns in the table and I know there are lot of rows since you are doing sum(). UNION will try aggregate the data so use UNION ALL, and you need to use some-sort of UNION between to result set to appear as one result set. Else it needs to be done via the application level using the server side script.

Comment: is not possible to use the same resultset for these kind of operataion in query itself.??

Comment: that will be way complicated, you will endup un-necessary joins and all and I cant even think of those ugly query.

Comment: its taking more than 15 mins to retrieve temp table records. if i use union it ll be more than 30 mins. its also complicated rite ?

Comment: 15 minutes for just `select * from temp` ? How many records do you have in that table. Are u using some where condition ? if yes then make sure temp table is well indexed.

Comment: i used some join conditions in that. its well optimized. This query processing more than 15 tables. i used temp for example here. Its min execution time is 15 mins.

Comment: Well I dont think the JOIN is optimized since its taking 15 mins thats way long, you may need to post the actual query being used. along with what explain plan shows.